# Tracking Volunteer Hours Using Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to find an efficient way to keep track of volunteer hours for each member of a high school volunteer club using Google Sheets. Right now, I have four sheets, one for members of each grade. On the horizontal axis, I list every event and how many hours they volunteer for (or don't volunteer). However, it takes up a lot of columns and I end up having to continually add columns which is a pain, especially when passing the document on for the next "generation" of club officers.

I was thinking of having one sheet for all the members and another for all the events with names and hours of each person who volunteered. The only problem is, I want the main sheet to be able to search through the event sheet for a certain name and then add the hours that correspond to that found name to the total hours on the main sheet.

Is it even possible to search through a different sheet and return a value other than the index? To return a value in a cell next to that of the name?

Comment: VLOOKUP? INDEX-MATCH?

Comment: But don't those only return the indexes of the name I'm looking for?

Comment: Index returns the value of a subscripted range, match creates the index

Comment: So could I use match to return the index of the name and then use index to return the value of the cell next to the cell of that index I just found using match?

Comment: That is correct

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this. For a one function solution use [QUERY](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en).